# Proving finite composition of functions using mathematical induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Baire one function. I need to prove $f^n$ is Baire one for $n=1,2,\dots,k$ by using [$\epsilon-\delta$ characterization of Baire one functions](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-00-05826-3/S0002-9939-00-05826-3.pdf):

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a Baire one function iff for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive function $\delta$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$|x-y|<\min\{\delta(x),\delta(y)\}\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$

where $f^n=f\circ f^{n-1}$ and $f^1=f$. [In this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228814932_Functions_Whose_Composition_With_Baire_Class_One_Functions_Are_Baire_Class_One) is shown that composition of two Baire one functions is not necessarily Baire one. But, I think there is still a possibility to prove $f^n$, $n=1,2,\dots,k$ is Baire one. Here is my attempt.
**For $n=1$**, it is clear that $f$ is Baire one.
**For $n=2,\dots, k$**, I try to prove it by using mathematical induction.
**For the base step**, I need to show that $f^n$ is Baire one for $n=2$.
*Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is Baire 1, then there exists a positive function $\delta_1:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$*, such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$|x-y|<\min\{\delta_1(x),\delta_1(y)\}\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$
*Let $\eta=\frac{1}{2}\min\{\delta_1(f(x)),\delta_1(f(y)),\epsilon\}>0$. Since $f$ is Baire one, there exists a positive function $\delta_2:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$*, such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$|x-y|<\min\{\delta_2(x),\delta_2(y)\}\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\eta<\min\{\delta_1(f(x)),\delta_1(f(y))\}.$$
Therefore, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$|x-y|<\min\{\delta_2(x),\delta_2(y)\}\Rightarrow |f(f(x))-f(f(y))|=|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|<\epsilon.$$
Thus, $f^2$ is Baire one.
**For induction step**, assume that $f^n$ is Baire one for $n=m\le k-1$ and I need to prove that $f^n$ is Baire one for $n=m+1$.
Note that $f^{m+1}=f\circ f^m$, where $f$ and $f^m$ are Baire one. From the base step, we have that $f^2=f\circ f$ is Baire one where $f$ is Baire one. Therefore $f^{m+1}=f\circ f^m$ is Baire one.
Then, I conclude that $f^n$ is Baire one for $n=1,2,\dots,k$.
However, I have some questions:

1. For the base step, is it allow to prove like that?
   I feel strange in the italic sentences since it appears twice but with different positive function, i.e. $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. Also for the first, I use $\epsilon>0$ and for the second, I use $\eta>0$.
2. Is the induction step correct?

Sorry for the long question, I will appreciate for any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like $\eta$ is circular, as $\eta$ depends on $x,y$, where $x,y$ are chosen later. In other words, the positive number $\eta$ should be independent of any point $x,y$

Answer (score 0):

The proof "For the base step" seems circular, as $\eta$ depends on $x,y$, causing $\delta_2$ depends on $x,y$ as well.

More precisely, if we want to prove $f^2$ is Baire-$1$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ characterization, we need to prove the following.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$|x-y|<\min\{\delta(x),\delta(y)\}\Rightarrow |f^2(x)-f^2(y)|<\epsilon.$$

**Note that $\delta$ can only depend on $\epsilon$.**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. In your proof, you let $\delta=\delta_2$, which depends on $\eta$.
But the choice of $\eta$ depends on $x,y$.
This means that for different $x,y$, we would get different $\eta$, and thus different $\delta$, which does not fulfill the positive function $\delta$ in the characterization.

Comment: If $\delta$ can only depend on $\epsilon$, how about the $\delta$ in these links? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783938 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3953066, where the positive function $\delta$ can depend on $x$.